# number of real solution of $\sin x+2\sin 2x = 3+3\sin 3x\;\forall x\in \left[0,\pi\right]$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

> Number of real solution of $\sin x+2\sin 2x = 3+3\sin 3x\;\forall x\in \left[0,\pi\right]$

**My try:** I have tried graphing. Using the graphs of $$y=\sin x+2\sin 2x \;\;\; \text{and} \;\;\; y=3+3\sin 3x,$$

I got two points of intersection of these graph in $x\in \left[0,\pi\right]$, but I did not understand how I can prove it without using graphs. Help me.

Thanks

Comment: You mean "these graph in $x \in [0, \pi]$" right, not $2 \pi$?

Comment: Yes $x\in [0,\pi]$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, there is a more elegant, and slightly shorter, way to solve the problem.

For the solution to be self-contained, I recall how I had transformed the initial equation in the following way, using relationships $\sin 2x = 2 \sin x \cos x$ and $\sin 3x = 3 \sin x (4 \cos^2 x -1)$:

$$\dfrac{4}{3} \sin x (1+\cos x-3 \cos^2 x)=1$$

Letting $X=\cos x$, which realize a one-to-one onto, i.e., bijective, mapping $(0,\pi) \rightarrow (-1,1)$),

we obtain the equivalent equation :

$$\dfrac{4}{3}(1+X)-4X^2-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-X^2}}=0 \ \ \ (1)$$

Let us give the name $f(x)$ to the LHS of (1). $f$ is $C^{\infty}$ on interval $I=(-1,1)$.

The central fact is that $f''<0$ on $I$ (see formulas and figure at the bottom).

Thus $f'$ is strictly $\searrow$ on $I$.

But  $f'(-1_{+}) = \lim_{X \rightarrow -1} f'(X)=+\infty$, and $f'(1_{-}) = \lim_{X \rightarrow 1} f'(X)=-\infty$.

Consequently, there exist a unique $X_0$ such that $f'(X_0)=0$.

For any $X \in (-1,X_0), f'(X)>0$, then $f$ is strictly $\nearrow$ on $(0,X_0)$ from $-\infty$ to $f(X_0)$ and  strictly $\searrow$ on $(X_0,1)$ from $f(X_0)$ to $-\infty$.

Moreover $f(X_0)$, being the max. of all values $f(X)$, is $>0$ because $f(0)=1/3>0$.

Thus, by a classical reasoning on the two intervals of monotonicity of $f$, there are exactly two roots for equation $f(X)=0$.

---

The affirmations above are easily checked by inspecting the following formulas:

$f'(X)=\dfrac{4}{3}-8X-X(1-X^2)^{-3/2}$

$f''(X)=-8-(1+2X^2)(1-X^2)^{-5/2}$

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A rigorous answer can be given, in the spirit of the remark of @lovsovs

Using relationships $\sin 2x = 2 \sin x \cos x$ and $\sin 3x = 3 \sin x (4 \cos^2 x -1)$, the given equation becomes:

$$4 \sin x (1+\cos x-3 \cos^2 x)=3$$

Letting $X=\cos x$ (which is a one-to-one onto (i.e., bijective) mapping $(0,\pi) \rightarrow (-1,1)$),

we obtain the equivalent equation :

$$1+X-3X^2=\dfrac{3/4}{\sqrt{1-X^2}} \ \ \ (1)$$

Let $f(X)$, resp. $g(X)$ be, resp, the LHS and RHS of (1).

It suffice now to consider intervals of monotonicity for continuous functions $f$ and $g$ thus defined. We are going to consider 3 of them, $I_1=(-1,0), I_2=(0,1/6)$ and $I_3=(1/6,1)$.

$f$ is strictly increasing on $I_1=(-1,1/6)$, strictly decreasing on $(1/6, 1)$.

$g$ is strictly decreasing on $(-1,0)$, strictly increasing on $(0, 1)$.

1) As $\lim_{X \rightarrow -1} g(X) = +\infty$ and $f(-1)=-3$ whereas $f(0)>g(0)$, due to the fact that $f$ is increasing while $g$ is decreasing, there is a single root $X_1$ on interval $I_1=(-1,0)$.

2) For $X \in I_2=[0,1/6]$, $f(X) > g(X)$ (Explanation (*) below). So no root can exist in $I_2$.

3) On interval $I_3=(1/6,1)$, $f$ (resp $g$) is strictly decreasing (resp. increasing), with

a) $f(1/6)>g(1/6)$ (because $13/12>1>9/(2 \sqrt{35})$).

b) $f(1)=-1$ whereas $\lim_{X \rightarrow 1} g(X) = +\infty$.

Thus, there is a single root $X_2$ on interval $I_3$.

Explanation (*): Let us consider any  $X \in I_2=(0,1/6)$ ; on the one hand $f(X) > f(0)=1$ because $f$ is strictly increasing ; on the other, $g(X) < g(1/6)=9/(2\sqrt{35})<1$ because $g$ is strictly increasing on $I_2$. Thus $\forall X \in I_2, f(X)>g(X)$.

A last remark for the sake of perfect rigor: as we have worked on open intervals, we have to assert that neither $0$ nor $1/6$ are roots of (1).

Editing: on very small details.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only after the *number* of solutions in the interval and not what the solutions are, you can simply split the functions into their constituent monotonic functions and pick out some interval in which one of the monotonic functions grows bigger/smaller than the other; this way, because they are continuous, you know that they have intersected. If you need it, I'd be happy to provide an example of this method, just let me know.

It is not elegant, but it gets the job done!

Answer (score 1):

Define $c=\cos x,\,s=\sin x$ so, by de Moivre's theorem, $\sin 2x=2cs,\,\sin 3x=s\left(3c^2-s^2\right)=s\left(3-4s^2\right)$. Thus $$s\left(1+4c\right)=3+3s\left(3-4s^2\right),\,4cs=3+8s-12s^3,\,16s^2\left(1-s^2\right)=\left(3+8s-12s^3\right)^2.$$ The final expression is a degree-$6$ polynomial in $s$, viz. $$144s^6-176^4-72s^3+48s^2+48s+9=0.$$ Unfortunately solving this polynomial requires numerical methods, and each solution must be checked for (i) which if either resulting $c=\pm\sqrt{1-s^2}$ works and (ii) which solutions if any exist in the desired range for said pairs of $c,\,s$.